# Replacing a pull-chain fan with a smart fan

Tags: lighting, ceiling-fan

[image]I realize there are many similar questions that have been asked, but none that I have found that apply to my situation. I'm trying to replace an old pull-chain fan with a new smart fan I purchased, and the wiring situation is boggling my mind.

First of all, in the ceiling, the old fan (with a light) was connected simply via a red wire and a white wire, with two pull chains to control either the fan and the light. But what's more is that above those two wires, there are 4 black wires that are all nutted together, three white wires that are all nutted together and two red wires that are nutted together. Disconnecting one of these wires at a time seems to turn off power to one other unrelated outlet in the room. My new ceiling fan, which has a black wire, blue wire, red wire and a green wire. It has a fan and a light as well.

The old light was controlled by one wall switch, which was actually in a double gang box with another switch that controlled a separate light in the adjacent hallway. Each of these switches have a cable with 2 red wires, 1 black wire and 1 white wire.  The two black wires and two white wires are nutted together, respectively, while one of the red wires is attached to the top of each switch and the other is attached to the bottom.  There is also one separate, very short red wire that connects to the top of each switch along with the other two red wires, joining them.

The switch for the new smart fan looks like this (attached). Any ideas? [image]

Comment: Leave all the wiring in the ceiling alone! As you've discovered, the box to which the fan is mounted is _also_ used as a junction box for unswitched wiring to outlets. There is nothing unusual or odd about this at all. Please [edit] your post to indicate the exact make and model of the new fan, and also include a clear, focused picture of the wiring in the box (you'll probably have to hold the fan while someone else takes the pic). Do not disconnect the existing wiring until you've got good directions - it will make your life _much_ easier.

Comment: Can you post photos of the wiring in the boxes involved please?

Comment: Ok, I tried my best to take photos, but there are so many wires in the ceiling and they are coming from such an odd angle that none of them came out clearly.  So instead I drew this diagram, which is 100% accurate.  If this does not help, I will post the photos, no matter how chaotic they look.

Comment: @MichaelJKozloski -- are those red/white/black wires between the switch and the fan in two separate cables, or are they all in one cable or conduit?

Comment: They are all in one conduit. At the switch there are 2 reds, 1 black and 1 white coming out from one conduit, and in the ceiling, in the middle conduit with the red wire that hangs down, there are again 2 reds, 1 black and 1 white.

Comment: @MichaelJKozloski -- can you get us a clear shot of the innards of the switch box please?